# node.js has no prompt after compilation

Tags: node.js, arm, cross-compiling

I've tried cross-compiling node.js for arm, and when I run the file node does nothing. Any idea on what I can do to find out what's wrong as there isn't any output?

Comment: If you don't find your answer here is a link to already compiled version of node for arm https://github.com/TooTallNate/node/downloads

Comment: Thank you but it's for another ARM version.